# CORBA sequence memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sequence, corba

I am having a problem with a sequence of sequences in CORBA. I could resolve the problem with a non elegant solution (at least for me is not elegant).

The (not real) code  that generate memory leak is like:

```
{
   IntMatrix m;
   m.lenght(100);
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      m[i].lenght(99);
   }
   //Send 'm' matrix and exit from this scope
}
```

The (non elegant) solution  is like:

```
{
  IntMatrix m;
  m.lenght(100);
  intSeq s;
  s.lenght(99);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
      m[i] = s;
  }
  //Send 'm' matrix and exit from this scope
}
```

I had been looking for a cause in Internet and I could only found text about a flag named "release".

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information. Please show the IDL for `IntMatrix` and `IntSeq`. And is this code running on the server or client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you say 'Send m matrix' you are on the client side.

I think the first piece of code is correct. If you have a memory leak, it could due to a bug in the ORB implementation your are using.

Comment: What do you think the best solution in my situation is?

Comment: Just patch your ORB. If you comment the send call and the leak dissapear, the problem is in your ORB. I know that it happens in some ACE TAO versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to return a sequence of sequences from a server implementation.

In that case, the IDL to C++ mapping requires you to "new up" the sequence:

Try something like this:

```
IntMatrix_var m = new IntMatrix;
m->length(100);
for (CORBA::ULong i = 0; i < m->length(); ++i)
{
   m[i].length(99);
   for (CORBA::ULong j = 0; j < m[i].length(); ++j)
   {
      m[i][j] = someValue;
   }
}
return m._retn();
```